# 'invalid assignment' when trying to place html tag in javascript

Tags: javascript, html

I'm trying to run `Plugin:RenderURL` inside some `javascript`, normally it's placed in some `html` element like an `<a href='[Plugin:RenderURL ..]'>` and fired once link is clicked.
When I try code below i get `ReferenceError: invalid assignment left-hand side`
Is there any way to place this inside javascript?

```
renderParams = "this is the value i'd like submitted";
[Plugin:RenderURL pr1.value="renderParams" pr1.key="CUSTOM_CONTEXT" pr1.mode="set" pr1.type="public"];
```

`Plugin:RenderURL` is an IBM WCM tag, http://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSHRKX_8.5.0/mp/social/plrf_rendr_plugin_render_url.html

This is how the second line looks in a browser ..
    p0/IZ7_11M21IS0K0RK40A242C2DP18I5=CZ6_11M21IS0KO5D20ASH9TSF510G2=MECUSTOM_CONTEXT!renderParams==/#Z7_11M21IS0K0RK40A242C2DP18I5;

Comment: You're going to want to look at what the code ends up looking like *in the browser*. That's where the error's coming from.

Comment: OK well that doesn't look like valid JavaScript code, does it? Do you want that stuff to be inside a JavaScript string or something? If so, you'll have to surround it with quotes.

Comment: I'm going to set it to be window.location, but looks like `renderParams` is not being evaluated? instead just placing the variable name in url/string

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found another way to set a `RenderParam` within `js` ..

```
var f = document.createElement('form');
f.setAttribute('method','get');
f.setAttribute('action','[Plugin:RenderURL copyCurrentParams="false"]');

var input = document.createElement('input');
input.setAttribute('type','text');
input.setAttribute('name','CUSTOM_CONTEXT');
input.value = renderParams;

var s = document.createElement('input');
s.setAttribute('type','submit');
s.setAttribute('value','Submit');

f.appendChild(input);
f.appendChild(s);
f.submit();
```

Answer (score 0):

Perusing the [Render URL Plugin documentation](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSHRKX_8.5.0/mp/social/plrf_rendr_plugin_render_url.dita), I see no way to load that value using JavaScript. As far as I can tell the prefix is processed server side meaning that no matter how hard you try the value is going to be defined well before your script runs.

Only thing I can think of is to get the `id` of the rendered HTML Element you'd like to pass `renderParams` to and use that id as the JavaScript selector and load the string after the page has been delivered from the server.